# "An extrinsic failed" when following Add a Pallet to Your Runtime tutorial

Tags: substrate, polkadot

I've added nicks pallet as in [Add a Pallet to Your Runtime](https://substrate.dev/docs/en/tutorials/add-a-pallet/interact-with-a-pallet) tutorial

My changes are here https://github.com/led73/substrate-node-template/commit/8f3025a73b35804edf7c8dd7cd5630b387f2d344

But when I try to interact with the pallet and `setName`, it fails with event

```
system:ExtrinsicFailed:: (phase={"ApplyExtrinsic":1})-0
DispatchError: {"Module":{"index":9,"error":0}}, DispatchInfo: {"weight":50000000,"class":"Normal","paysFee":"Yes"}
An extrinsic failed. \[error, info\]
```

Where should I look what went wrong?

[Screenshot is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5IjS.jpg)

Answer (score 4):

Your problem has an easy fix, check [this line](https://github.com/led73/substrate-node-template/commit/8f3025a73b35804edf7c8dd7cd5630b387f2d344#diff-0ec06ea58bd455f09ce6b3bb4c2c1c0d37bda51c1e1be2151c560c9c973959ecR498) of your nicks pallet code, you are defining a minimum length of 8 characters, yet your test with `larry` will fail, as it doesn't reach the minimum requested length.

For future occasions there it goes a tip when a dispatch error happens.
`index:9` and  `error:0` are the index of the pallet in `construct_runtime!` which is throwing the error, and the index of the error in the `#[pallet::error]` definition of the pallet concerned.

Error with index 0 for nicks pallet being [this one](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/nicks/src/lib.rs#L107)